# Hide linefeed and tab characters in xcode editor

Tags: xcode

As can be seen in the [screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/362683/Xcode.png) the editor in xcode has started to show linefeeds and tab characters, normally invisible characters. I can't for the life of me find a way to hide them again and i have no idea why they started to show. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, it was the bracket matching xcode plugin that caused it. Removing that restored order in the universe and xcode.